# Swift: transitionFromView flip whole screen instead of view

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimationtransition

I have a weird issue with swift. I am trying to flip two views, not the whole screen but it flips the whole screen.

It has been asked before on here but no answer:

[flip animation in swift flips whole view not subviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27120237/flip-animation-in-swift-flips-whole-view-not-subviews)

This is the references to the views I have (I have confirmed they only take up part of the screen):

```
@IBOutlet var frontview: UIView!
@IBOutlet var backview: UIView!
```

And this is my code for flipping:

```
func flipCard() { 

   if (showingBack) {
        UIView.transitionFromView(backview, toView: frontview, duration: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromRight, completion: nil)
        showingBack = false
    } else {
        UIView.transitionFromView(frontview, toView: backview, duration: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft, completion: nil)
        showingBack = true
    }       
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: both `backview` and `frontview` flip the whole screen

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I know that is my question?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I understand , yes it flips the whole screen for both.

Comment: oh whats the frame of your `backview`

Comment: Just had a look at the other answer and it seems much more applicable to your problem so I deleted my answer. If it doesn't work for whatever reason just send me a message. :)

Comment: Btw it shouldn't be a problem sending info to the container as it is an outlet. You can send whatever info you want to it. :)

Comment: That evample for the other answer is what I used to work it out. The code is exactly the same as mine and will have the same problem.

Comment: Honestly I would prefer to do container view as you suggest but i had no end of trouble making it try to flip when segue and then another guy said it is less memory efficiwnt. If I could get it working with a container view it makes layout so much easier.

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you call `UIView.transitionFromView(backView, toView: frontView ...` is it flips the parent of those two views. Presumably the parent in your case is the root view of the ViewController, so to get it to flip just those views instead of the "whole screen" you would just need to embed both `backView` and `frontView` in another view.

There's more details in [this article.](https://www.twilio.com/blog/ios-view-animations-transitions-swift)

Answer (score 0):

Try [This](http://www.codingricky.com/flipping-cards-with-swift-and-uikit/) example. I think you are looking something like this. instead of imageView try UIView in your case.

Comment: Thanks but this is the example i used to make my code. It is exactly the same and will have the same issue.

Comment: I think the issue is with the IBOutlets. try making your view programmatically if satisfies your requirement. i have tried it. and it is working fine. with creating views programmatically .