# How to sort array of UIImages?

Tags: arrays, swift, animation, swift3, uiimage

**I have 3 images, I need to implement them with animation. How i can display each image separately on the screen using a loop? help me please**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var imageArray: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "1")!, UIImage(named: "2")!, UIImage(named: "3")!]
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(handleTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
    
    private func setImageSettings(to image: UIImage?) -> UIImageView {
        let pictureParams = UIImageView(image: image)
        pictureParams.frame.size = CGSize(width: 400, height: 300)
        pictureParams.center = view.center
        pictureParams.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        view.addSubview(pictureParams)
        return pictureParams
    } 
    func moveImages(_ targetView: UIImageView) {
        UIImageView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, options: [], animations: {targetView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: targetView.frame.origin.x + 320, y: targetView.frame.origin.y )}, completion: nil)
    }   
    func sortImages() {
        for image in imageArray{
            moveImages(setImageSettings(to: image))
        }
    }
    @objc private func handleTimer(_ sender: Timer) {
        sortImages()
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the community. Could you be more specific on what you want? Is there like a specific layout you want? or just animate the image views

Comment: @VisalRajapakse Thank you! I need a slider for pictures with the specified timer parameters. 3 pictures were flipped one after another on the screen. at the moment I have 3 pictures displayed at once

Comment: See if you can use the following thread for your use case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39519102/ios-card-flip-animation/46333715

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. You have a function called `sortImages()` that doesn't sort anything - it loops through all of your images at once, creates an image view for each, and attempts to animate each image view, even though those image views have never been added to the view hierarchy. I don't see how you ever see any of your images shown on the screen.

Comment: @DuncanC how can i get the code to work correctly?

Comment: You need to update your question to show how your images are being displayed on screen. Do you have image views in your storyboard that have images installed in them?

Comment: The title of your question is "How to sort array of UIImages?" And yet you don't say what you mean by sorting. Your question seems to be about creating a sequence of animations. "Sorting" means to re-order an array into a specific order based on some criteria. You could sort an array of letters, `["b", "d", "c", "a"]` into alphabetical order (`["a", "b", "c", "d"]`, for example. What does your question have to do with sorting? You need to clearly describe what you are trying to do, and explain the setup of your app.

Comment: In my comment above I said your code "...attempts to animate each image view, even though those image views have never been added to the view hierarchy." I missed the call to `addSubview()` in your function `setImageSettings()`

Comment: Can you please edit your question to make it clear what you are actually asking about? (e.g. change the title from "How to sort array of images" to something like "How to animate images across the screen one at a time?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to animate one image at a time, appearing in the middle of your view controller's view, and then moving up to the top of the view, you could change your code like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var imageIndex = 0
    var imageArray: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "1")!, UIImage(named: "2")!, UIImage(named: "3")!]
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
        let timer: Timer? = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(handleTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    
    private func setImageSettings(to image: UIImage?) -> UIImageView {
        let pictureParams = UIImageView(image: image)
        pictureParams.frame.size = CGSize(width: 400, height: 300)
        pictureParams.center = view.center
        pictureParams.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        view.addSubview(pictureParams)
        return pictureParams
    } 

    func moveImages(_ targetView: UIImageView) {
        UIImageView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, options: [], animations: {targetView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: targetView.frame.origin.x + 320, y: targetView.frame.origin.y )}, completion: nil)
    }   

    func animateImages() {
        // Fetch an image from the array
        let image = imageArray[imageIndex]

        // Create the animation for that image
        moveImages(setImageSettings(to: image))

        // Move on to the next image index
        imageIndex += 1

        // If we are past the end of the array, stop.
        if imageIndex == imagesArray.count {
            timer.invalidate() 
        }
    }

    @objc private func handleTimer(_ sender: Timer) {
        animateImages()
    }
}
```

Comment: don't you either want a repeating timer or to set a new timer on each execution loop?

Comment: Oops. I thought the OP’s timer **was** repeating. Thanks for catching that. Time to edit my answer…

Comment: BTW, your SO avatar is triggering my Anatidaephobia.

Comment: It's probably due a change.  How are you with puffins? ;-)

Comment: I'm fine with puffins, but I just know that somewhere, a duck is watching me! :)

Comment: Note that you can do the animation using a repeating timer and no loop. Each time the timer fires, it animates one more of the images. The other way to do it would be to go through a loop, creating a series of animations, where the first has a 0 delay, the second has enough delay that it triggers when the first has completed, etc.